# Adding ladels to graphic data to XYPlot, XYShapeRenderer

Tags: java, jfreechart

i'm using jfreechart, and i need to add labels to my series data. There are bold dots on graphic and they need labels... Following code does not work.

[image: screenshot]

```
    XYSeries series = new XYSeries("Average Size");
    series.add(.60, .70);
    XYDataset xyDataset = new XYSeriesCollection(series);

    XYItemRenderer rend = new XYShapeRenderer(); 

    XYItemLabelGenerator  generator = new XYItemLabelGenerator() {

        @Override
        public String generateLabel(XYDataset xyd, int i, int i1) {
            return "Some label?"; 
        }
    };
    //SeriesItemLabelGenerator
    rend.setBaseItemLabelGenerator(generator);
    rend.setBaseItemLabelsVisible(true);

    ItemLabelPosition pos = new ItemLabelPosition(ItemLabelAnchor.CENTER, TextAnchor.TOP_LEFT);

    rend.setBasePositiveItemLabelPosition(pos);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is that XYShapeRenderer(http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/src-html/org/jfree/chart/renderer/xy/XYShapeRenderer.html), which extends AbstractXYItemRenderer, does not implement ItemLabelGenerator logic yet.

So, or you will need to use another Renderer. 
For example, XYLineAndShapeRenderer(http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/src-html/org/jfree/chart/renderer/xy/XYLineAndShapeRenderer.html) implements it:

```
// draw the item label if there is one...
if (isItemLabelVisible(series, item)) {
  drawItemLabel(g2, orientation, dataset, series, item, xx, yy,(y1 < 0.0));
}
```

Or you will need to extend XYShapeRenderer yourself and add the label drawing logic, using any of the other Renderer's source code as an example.

Comment: Hi, can you tell, my code is theoretically rigth? I can't find any example to compare or to see how it must be constructed.

Comment: Yes, it is. I replaced XYShapeRenderer with XYLineAndShapeRenderer in your code and the label was added. Your code is entirely correct.

Comment: Thanks much! It works with XYLineAndShapeRenderer. But i can't understand how to change it's label font.

Comment: to change shape u can use rend.setSeriesShape(0, new Ellipse2D.Double(-3, -3, 6, 6));

Comment: Found solution. If you wan't to change font use this rend.setBaseItemLabelPaint(Color.GREEN); rend.setBaseItemLabelFont(new Font("Arial", Font.BOLD, 14));